# Compiling C using make in windows (MinGW)

Tags: c, makefile, mingw

I am following the book "Learn C the Hard Way" and I have reached the section where you compile the code using makefiles. I keep getting errors that the file was not found when running make clean.
Here is the error followed by the make file and the directory

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\C Code\HARD WAY\Dust off that compiler>make clean
rm -f main.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f main.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [makefile:7: clean] Error 2
```

```
EXECUTABLE=main.exe
    
CC="C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"
    
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
clean:
    rm -f main
```

[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxsZB.png)

EDIT: I removed the .c from the "rm -f main" as it seems to be a small error but has made no difference to the end result

EDIT 2: I worked out that the make file is issuing linux commands which is why it wasn't working, replacing rm with del fixes the issue

Comment: Why do you want to remove the C source file when you run `make clean`? Normally, the `clean` target is used to remove the output files.

Comment: I don't know why, the book has not explained that part

Comment: Perhaps it cannot find 'rm'?

Comment: What happens if you type `rm` (with no arguments) from the command prompt?

Comment: Thanks for the help, these are linux commands not windows so it will not work

Comment: Pro Tip: when writing code, never store it in a directory where the pathname contains whitespace.  It will, in general, be nothing but a source of needless grief and annoyance.  Second Pro Tip: when working with cross-platform systems always use forward slash, never backslash, as a directory separator.

Comment: Thank you for the pro tips,  will be sure to use them from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that the make file is issuing linux commands which is why it wasn't working, replacing rm with del and removing -f fixes the issue

Comment: If this indeed satisfies all that was asked in your question, Please mark it as accepted so others will know.  (Hollow check mark to left of score.)

Comment: I cannot accept it, it says I have to wait a day still